# Running a second instance of an SDL program causes a system-wide freeze

Tags: opengl, graphics, sdl

I'm making a multiplayer game using SDL, however, at some point I've stopped being able to run two instances of it concurrently. The first instance runs without problems, however, once the second one is launched, its render thread hangs. It manifests as a system-wide graphics freeze, e.g. I can no longer move the mouse and nothing on the screen is updated inside  or  outside  the SDL window(s). After a couple of seconds, the render thread recovers only to freeze again momentarily. SDL does manage to catch a quit event if I've sent it and exit. Then, the terminal's window with stdout of the program is updated (that's how I can assume that the update thread was running alright, there is a large interval where only its debugging info is present).

By removing piece of code from the render procedure I was able to determine that these three uncommented SDL calls were what was causing the delay:

```
void Renderer::render() {
  SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(sdlRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 255);
  SDL_RenderClear(sdlRenderer);

  // for (auto target : targets) {
  //   target->render(this);
  //   // std::cout << "rendered object with sceneId " << target->target->sceneId << std::endl; 
  // }

  // auto targetCopy = newTargets;

  // for (auto newTarget : targetCopy) {
  //   targets.push_back(newTarget);
  //   // std::cout << "adding render target" << std::endl;
  // }

  // newTargets.clear();

  SDL_RenderPresent(sdlRenderer);
}
```

What could be causing this behavior?

This is the SDL initialization code for further information, also attempted without acceleration:

```
SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO);

int fullscreenType = 0; // SDL_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN_DESKTOP;

int windowFlags = fullscreenType | SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_BORDERLESS |
                  SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI;

int rendererFlags = SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED | SDL_RENDERER_PRESENTVSYNC;

SDL_Window *window =
    SDL_CreateWindow("Game", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
                      1000, 1000, windowFlags);

SDL_Renderer *sdlRenderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(window, -1, rendererFlags);
SDL_RenderSetLogicalSize(sdlRenderer, 1000, 1000);

IMG_Init(IMG_INIT_PNG);
```

I'm running Manjaro with GNOME on Wayland. Acer Swift 3. Output of `glxinfo | grep OpenGL`:

```
OpenGL vendor string: Intel Open Source Technology Center
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 620 (Kaby Lake GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5 (Core Profile) Mesa 17.3.5
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 3.0 Mesa 17.3.5
OpenGL shading language version string: 1.30
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 17.3.5
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
OpenGL ES profile extensions:
```

On X.Org this behavior is slightly different (I can move the mouse around but everything is unresponsive), but the same underlying freeze issue is present.

Comment: A wild quess, mostly based on the fact, that you're on Intel graphics,  would be, that no proper buffer swap command is issued. The Intel drivers are a little bit annoying, because they rely entirely on the buffer swap to flush and synchronize the presentation queue. What I guess to happen is, that your render loops are running unthrottled and push several frames per display refresh interval. With just one process doing this, it kind of gets rate limited. For a quick check add a `usleep(20000)` after `SDL_RenderPresent`.

Comment: Alco could you try out what happens if you (reliably) remove Wayland from the picture? Maybe the X server you start just runs as a Xwayland client. For obvious reasons off-screen surfaces (like Wayland clients use) have no sensible definition of "buffer swap", hence these will not see presentation queue synchronization events.

Comment: @datenwolf that was one lucky wild guess lol

Comment: @datenwolf can you post  that as an answer? also yeah I tried it with X, see my edit, similar thing happened

Comment: @datenwolf another fact that might interest you is that I have SDL's vsync enabled, which would I thought do the same thing. any idea as to why this happens then?

Comment: Let's just say, that vsync is a mess; even more so with the Intel drivers. The goal of Wayland was (among other things) to clean this up. But as they say, the way to hell is paved with good intentions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

<s>A wild</s> An *educated* guess, mostly based on the fact, that you're on Intel graphics, would be, that no proper buffer swap command is issued. The Intel drivers are a little bit annoying, because they rely entirely on the buffer swap to flush and synchronize the presentation queue.

What I suppose what's happening is, that your render loops are running unthrottled and push **a lot** of frames per display refresh interval. But why would this happen, if you're asking for a double buffered window? The answer: Wayland. The Wayland model (which actually makes a lot of sense!) is, that clients render into off-screen surfaces, which are managed by the compositor, and the compositor itself is responsible for doing the "composition" (hence the name), i.e. putting it all together on the screen and synchronizing with the display. However for this to work the clients' render results must be ready, before composition starts.

Obviously an off-screen surface doesn't swap, so any request of "buffer swap" or synchronization must be forwarded to the compositor. And if that doesn't work properly, trouble begins.

With just one process constantly pushing frames, it kind of gets rate limited; but with several processes stuffing the queue it looks like most of the GPU time is consumed up by the clients, with the Compositor starving for a change to insert a buffer swap that could flush/sync the presentation queue.

For a quick check add a `usleep(20000)` after `SDL_RenderPresent`.